# Selling living space to a non-Jew over pesach to get rid chametz

Tags: halacha, passover, transactions, home-house, bedikas-chametz

Is one allowed to temporarily sell their living space to a non-Jew in order to get rid of their chametz during pesach? If so, are they still obligated to do a bdikat chametz?

Comment: Will you be moving out of the space during Pesach and when will you be leaving. See discussions about renting the space to the non-Jew when you sell the chametz.

Comment: @sabbahillel I will be moving out of space during Pesach. How does time of departure prior to Pesach have an influence?

Comment: I posted an answer from Halachipedia.

Comment: If the mechira occured before the 14, he do not make any bdika. (rav Nissim Karelits make a special Shtar mechira with a part of mechira that occurs on 13 nissan)

Comment: But in the question you says that he want to stay at home for Pessach? A big problem...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to rent the apartment or the house to a non-Jew. You do not have to sell it. Also if you leave more than 30 days before Pesach you do not have to do Bedikat Chametz. Here are the citations from Halachipedia. There is much more at the link.

[Leaving for Pesach](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bedikat_Chametz#Leaving_for_Pesach)

> **Leaving for Pesach**
>
> If a person leaves one’s house more than 30 days before Pesach and
>   doesn’t plan to return for Pesach one doesn’t have to do Bedika but
>   rather just do Bitul when the times comes wherever one is. [14]
>
> If a person leaves one’s house within 30 days of Pesach and doesn’t
>   plan to return for Pesach one must do Bedika with a candle the night
>   before one leaves and then do Bitul Chametz afterwards, however the
>   Bedika is done without a Bracha. [15]
>
> Since one is not going to be home for Pesach it’s sufficient to do a
>   proper Bedika according to the law by just looking for the Chametz
>   (though not just a superficial look) and one doesn’t have to drive
>   oneself crazy like one does every year. [16]
>
> However if possible it’s preferable to appoint a שליח to do Beidika
>   for oneself at the proper time. [17] Some say that it’s better to do
>   it oneself before going rather than have a non-family member (such as
>   a neighbor) do it for oneself. [18]
>
> If one plans on returning before Pesach if there’s a fear one will
>   return on Erev Pesach without time for Bedika one should do it before
>   going, otherwise do it when one returns. [19]
>
> [14] S”A 436:1
>
> [15] S”A 436:1
>
> [16] Rav Schachter on OU Pre-Pesach Webcast 5771 between minutes 2:30
>   and 5
>
> [17] Mishna Brurah 436:1
>
> [18] Piskei Teshuvot 436:1
>
> [19] Mishna Brurah 436:9

[Renting one's house to a non-Jew](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bedikat_Chametz#Renting_one.27s_house_to_a_non-Jew)

> **Renting one's house to a non-Jew**
>
> If one is renting out one’s house and the Chametz in it to a non-Jew
>   for Pesach one will have exempted oneself from Bedika but it’s not
>   proper to do so, rather it’s correct to rent one’s house except for
>   one room and do Bedika without a Bracha in that room before one leaves
>   for Pesach. [20]
>
> The room which one leaves not rented in order to Bedika should be a room
>   which one usually brings Chametz otherwise there’ll be no
>   obligation of Bedika and one will have accomplished nothing by leaving
>   that room not rented. [21]
>
> [20]Rav Schachter on OU Pre-Pesach Webcast 5771 between minutes 2:30
>   and 5
>
> [21]Rav Yisrael Belsky on OU Pre-Pesach Webcast 5771 between minutes
>   10:30 and 11:30